# MSWord VBA Copy Text Out Of Autoshapes and Remove Them

Tags: vba, ms-word

Word 2016 and 2003 format document. I have a book, yes I wrote it, that needs to be converted to straight text. It is laid out with autoshapes containing text and I need to copy the text out and delete the autoshape. The attached macro will work somewhat, but not touching the SS autoshapes. I have also included a link to the shared directory containing the screenshot (Capture.png). Any ideas to accomplish this?
![Word Screenshot]: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/152P6DPQ0LzxtvLunddNeKdYASY2fFhQ2?usp=sharing

```
For oShape = ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
    If ActiveDocument.Shapes(oShape).TextFrame.HasText = True Then
        ActiveDocument.Shapes(oShape).Select

        strText = ActiveDocument.Shapes(oShape).TextFrame.TextRange.Text
        'oShape.ConvertToInlineShape
        ActiveDocument.Shapes(oShape).Delete
        Selection.TypeText strText
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Have you tried saving/printing the document as a PDF, then opening the PDF with Word 2016?

Comment: I don't see how that would help to pull the text out of the graphics since a PDF cements the textboxes and text together. but that may lead to the answer. I have a PDF tool at work which allows manipulation, so this may be a lead in the right direction.

Comment: Interesting thought - you learn something new every day. Opening the PDF in Word and then saving a txt did take the text out of the graphic blocks. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: So... problem solved - no additional answer required?